# stackexchange.redis throws timeout even after increasing timeout?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am getting the following error when trying to delete from my cache:

`Timeout performing DEL test.com, inst: 0, mgr: ExecuteSelect, err: never, queue: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: ORLWS052, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/pub-redis-16778.us-west-2-1.1.ec2.garantiadata.com:16778, keyHashSlot: 6928, IOCP: (Busy=3,Free=997,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=4091,Min=4,Max=4095), Local-CPU: 100% (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/master/Docs/Timeouts.md)`

I also get an similar timeout when updating.

I have no idea how to read this, so if anyone knows that would be helpful.

The size of the key I am trying to update or delete is 5515 bytes.

I also ran the `slowlog get` command and there is none (the length is 0)

I also tried to increase the timeout, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 3):

`IOCP: (Busy=3,Free=997,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=4091,Min=4,Max=4095), Local-CPU: 100%`

Please check your ICOP, WORKER busy threads and minimum threads. Also the CPU is 100%. The timeoutHelpLink was updated in the latest release.

https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts

> If we look at an example error message from StackExchange.Redis (build
>   1.0.450 or later), you will see that it now prints ThreadPool statistics (see IOCP and WORKER details below).
>
> `System.TimeoutException: Timeout performing GET MyKey, inst: 2, mgr:
>   Inactive,  queue: 6, qu: 0, qs: 6, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, 
>   IOCP: (Busy=6,Free=994,Min=4,Max=1000),  WORKER:
>   (Busy=3,Free=997,Min=4,Max=1000)`
>
> In the above example, you can see that for IOCP thread there are 6
>   busy threads and the system is configured to allow 4 minimum threads.
>   In this case, the client would have likely seen two 500 ms delays
>   because 6 > 4.
>
> Note that StackExchange.Redis can hit timeouts if growth of either
>   IOCP or WORKER threads gets throttled.
>
> Recommendation: Given the above information, it's recommend to set the
>   minimum configuration value for IOCP and WORKER threads to something
>   larger than the default value. We can't give one-size-fits-all
>   guidance on what this value should be because the right value for one
>   application will be too high/low for another application. This setting
>   can also impact the performance of other parts of complicated
>   applications, so you need to fine-tune this setting to your specific
>   needs. A good starting place is 200 or 300, then test and tweak as
>   needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input.  Where can I change these settings? What part of the code?  Also how did you come up with 2 500 ms delays? Is it 500ms for every thread over the min?

Comment: @xaisoft Do you check the link?

Comment: Yeah I saw it after the fact. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and managed to solve it by changing of `syncTimeout` parameter. By default it's 1000 ms.
https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html

According to the sources it also impacts on `AsyncTimeout`.
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/3f7e5466c6bbff96a3ed1130b637a097d21f3fed/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConfigurationOptions.cs#L171